# How to use lapplly function to do splitting data for categories

Tags: r, lapply

I want conduct Time Series Analysis, but for each category separately. If i have one group variable with 100 categories, it's easy to do, using this expression:

```
    lapply(1 : 100, function (i) { HoltWinters(mydata[, group == i], 
beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE) } )
```

But how can i conduct Time Series Analysis, if i have 2 group variables. I.e. i must split data on two group variables. For example , i must get result for
group 1=categoria№1 and group2=categoria№3
How using lapply function do that double splitting?

Comment: Just try `lapply(split(mydata,mydata[,c("grp1","grp2")]), function(x) HoltWinters(x, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE))` where `grp1` and `grp2` are the columns that define the groups.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `plyr` package

```
dlply(
  .data = mydata,
  .variables = ~group1 + group2,
  .fun = HoltWinters,
  beta = FALSE,
  gamma = FALSE
)
```